# Как сохраненный куки с сессии requests и засунуть в куки selenium'a

Tags: python

Смотрите, у меня есть который получает куки и из сессии берет эти куки функцией session.cookies.get_dict() и вот эти куки мне нужно вставить в куки браузера selenium помогите пожалуйста. не как не получается.

Comment: Уточните и улучшите ваш вопрос. Покажите что у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key, value in session.cookies.get_dict().items():
    driver.add_cookie({'name': key, 'value': value})
```

Если не сработало, примени `execute_script()` драйвера Selenium для добавления кук в браузер через JavaScript.

```
for key, value in session.cookies.get_dict().items():
    driver.execute_script(f"document.cookie = '{key}={value}';")
```

Еще можно так: сохрани куки в файл формата JSON, используя `json.dump()` и затем загрузить их в браузер с помощью модуля `selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities`

```
import json
with open('cookies.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(session.cookies.get_dict(), f)

with open('cookies.json', 'r') as f:
    cookies = json.load(f)

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Если не получилось, используй другого драйвера Selenium типа ChromeDriver или GeckoDriver.